# What is the proper name of the chapter illustration for Chapter 33 of The Order of the Phoenix?

Tags: harry-potter

When reading the 5th book of Harry Potter, I have been trying to name each of the chapter art at the beginning of the chapters as I am matching the chapter illustration to a certain part of the chapter content. However, I have found few resources available on the Internet concerning the names of the illustrations.

The only clue I have found for the chapter art of the 33rd chapter is from a quiz that asks people to name the chapters using descriptions of the chapter (quiz link as follows: https://www.sporcle.com/games/lostfan10/hp_illustrations).

According to this quiz, the name of the 33rd chapter art is "Umbridge leading Harry and Hermione into the Forbidden Forest." However, the chapter art itself clearly shows that it was Hermione leading the way, with Harry following immediately after and Umbridge at the back with a wand in her hand. I wonder if there are any other resources about the names and descriptions of all the chapter illustrations as these pictures are not always corresponding to the chapter titles in a plain way. I have to read the chapter through to find out what the chapter art represents and sometimes it is still rather confusing why a particular picture is used to represent this chapter (e.g. Chapter 34 Priori Incantatem, Goblet of Fire, with a pair of snake-like eyes as the chapter art).

So, back to my question, are there any online resources devoted to the naming of all the chapter illustrations? Have the illustrator Mary GrandPre herself been naming these illustrations? If not, who is naming and describing the chapter illustrations? Can any individual name the chapter art as they see fit?

I love these chapter art so much and have long been curious about their meanings and choice of use for each chapter. I truly hope there will be people discussing these illustrations in detail. That is why I have come up with this question.

Comment: I don't think that quiz is purporting to give the official names of the illustrations - it's just describing what they look like, based on the quiz-writers opinion. If the illustrations have any official names beyond the chapter titles you'd probably need to ask Mary GrandPré.

Comment: You're asking about the official name of a certain chapter's art, but your other questions suggests that you don't know any source for the other official names, or even know whose doing the naming. I have to wonder if you're asking for something that does not exist.

Comment: @Showsni Thanks for answering. The chapter illustrations are a great treasure and they help a lot with the reading of the 199 chapters of the Harry Potter series. I do hope Mary GrandPre have named these pictures. But I can settle for the quiz writer's names because they are actally rather accurate descriptions of the illustrations, although there are a couple of names that may need to be adjusted a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the "Skirmish in the Forbidden Forest" or "Dumbledore's Fake Secret Weapon"

The official name of Chapter 33 of the Order of the Phoenix is "Fight and Flight".

Hermione leads Harry and Umbridge into the forest, where they encounter centaurs. The Skirmish in the Forbidden Forest ensues, and Umbridge foolishly insults them and an angry centaur picks up Umbridge and carries her off screaming into the woods. When Hagrid's giant half-brother, Grawp crashes onto the scene, Hermione and Harry escape amid the chaos.

Harry, Ron and Hermione, along with Luna, Ginny and Neville fly to the Ministry of Magic on the school's Thestrals, unaware they are being lured into a trap.

The **Fight**: The Centaurs, Harry, and Hermione vs Umbridge

The **Flight**: Harry, Ron, Hermione, Luna, Ginny, and Neville fly to the Ministry of Magic.

Comment: Do you have anything to indicate that this is the *official* name of the illustration?

Comment: @ibid Thanks for asking the question in my mind. I wonder where more information about these wonderful illustrations can be found. I have checked Mary GrandPre's website and googled a lot but unfortunately there seems to be little information about how the pictures were created or named.

Comment: @PotterRead In the illustration, Umbridge , on the left of the picture, has her wand out, with Harry and Hermione in front of her and going towards the forest, which is seen on the far right of the picture.